# Numpy 1D arrays treated as column vectors when it comes to broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy

In the documentation on [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules), is is stated that two dimensions are compatible when either:

- they are equal or
- one of them is 1

This becomes clear with some of the examples that are shown, such as:

```
A      (4d array):  8 x 1 x 6 x 1
B      (3d array):      7 x 1 x 5
Result (4d array):  8 x 7 x 6 x 5
```

This seems clear enough. However, I've been unable to find a specific example/explanation as to why 1D arrays are only broadcastable with 2d arrays, when the 1d array's shape is compatible with that of the second axis of the 2d array.
So for instance:

```
np.ones((2,3)) * np.arange(3)

array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.]])
```

The 1d arange has been broadcast across the rows, as expected. However if we do:

```
np.ones((3, 2)) * np.arange(3)
```

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (3,)

We get an error for incompatible shapes. This might be quite simple, but I just want to know which is the correct interpretation. Is the reason behind this, that when it comes to broadcasting rules 1d arrays are treated as column vectors, and hence shape compatibility is checked along the second axis on the 2d array? And for larger arrays, is it always checked against the last axis on the larger ndarray?

Comment: The other rule is that it can add new leading dinensions.  (3,) to (1,3) is automatic.  To get a (3,1) you have add that size 1 dim yourself.

Comment: That 3d `B` becomes 1 x 7 x 1 x 5 during broadcasting..  It would fail if A was missing the trailing 1.

Comment: Yes. This becomes apparent by the fact that (2x3) and (3) are compatible. For all dims to be compatible, makes sense that the latter is reshaped to (1,3) as you mention, so that the second rule becomes valid. @hpaulj and they can be broadcast. Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the reason behind this, that when it comes to broadcasting rules 1d arrays are treated as column vectors, and hence shape compatibility is checked along the second axis on the 2d array?

On the contrary, they are treated as row vectors and stacked vertically. You can see it in [this figure](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html#figure-2) from a related article.

You can do the same sketch in the case you presented:

```
A   3 x 2    # np.ones((3, 2))
B   2 x 3    # np.ones((2, 3))
C       3    # np.arange(3)
```

Here `A*C` does not work, but `B*C` does. This is because `C` gets duplicated along the first dimension (i.e., rows). You can imagine missing dimensions as being "resized" by duplicating the dimensions coming after